# Rounded corners with C++

Tags: c++, opencv, magick++

I'm looking for some c++ drawing graphics library to create rounded corners with anti-aliasing option for dynamic keyboard key creator. I've already tested OpenCV and Magick++ functions but the result was not so good. Can anyone help me with this?

This is a sample of one code to create a rounded corner with Magick++ library

```
void create_rounded_image (int size, int border) {
    Magick::Image image_bk (Magick::Geometry (size, size), Magick::Color ("black"));

    image_bk.strokeColor ("white");
    image_bk.fillColor ("white");
    image_bk.strokeWidth(1);
    image_bk.draw (DrawableCircle(size, size, size*0.3, size*0.3));

    image_bk.write ("rounded.png");
}
```

This is the result I'm getting

[image: This is the result I'm getting]

This is the result I'm looking for

[image: This is the result I'm looking for]

Comment: The first image show aliasing, I don't know Magick++ but there isn't there an option to activate anti aliasing ?

Comment: You can also go with Cairo (C API, although): http://www.cairographics.org/

Answer (score 1):

Googling some online [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html), I found:

> strokeAntiAlias - bool - **Enable or disable anti-aliasing when drawing object outlines.**

I suggest:

```
image_bk.strokeAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: Why not use `bool` `true` instead of `1`?

Comment: @rozina, because C++. But yeah, I'll change it for clarity

Comment: It is just `true`, not `bool true` :) And I see the question has C and C++ tag. I wish people would not mix the two languages any more.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Lamar's answer. `Magick::Image.strokeAntiAlias` and `Magick::DrawableStrokeAntiAlias` is what you want. But I would suggest using `std::list<Drawable>` to generate a context stack. This would allow your application to manage *what-will-be-drawn* independently of image i/o.

```cpp
using namespace Magick;

size_t size = 405;
size_t border = 6;

std::list<Drawable> ctx;
ctx.push_back(DrawableStrokeAntialias(MagickTrue));
ctx.push_back(DrawableStrokeColor("#CAF99B"));
ctx.push_back(DrawableStrokeWidth(border));
ctx.push_back(DrawableFillColor("#68C77B"));
ctx.push_back(DrawableCircle(size*0.75, size*0.25, size*0.33, size*0.66));

Image image_bk( Geometry(size, size), Color("white"));
image_bk.draw(ctx);
```

[image: Rounded corners in C++]